# What tool should I use to find and move a large number of pictures in a bunch of folders on a hard drive?

Tags: windows, search

Like to the tune of 200k pictures. I think many of them are probably duplicates. I'd like to move them all to one folder and look at them.

1. find all pictures on a hard drive, recursively; hundreds of thousands of pictures
2. move all pics to a new folder

I've tried Windows Explorer and Teracopy and they both seem to choke.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AstroGrep. As you can see in the picture below you can search for multiple file types & keywords. When your search is over select the files and right click. Go to File Operations, copy and paste the files where you want. Not sure though how will it behave with 200k files. :)

[image]

Comment: Seemed great until I searched with this: `*.gif, *.png, *.jpg` -- no results. Trust me, there's thousands of those files in that folder. 310k files and no images? unlikely.

Comment: Ok I see the issue: the exclusions list by default contains .gif etc

Answer (score 0):

I have always liked Microsoft's [RichCopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx).  It is lightweight, yet extremely powerful.

Comment: I'm looking at it and don't see any way to filter the file types that are copied.